# Subobject classifier in $Sets^Q$

Tags: category-theory, functors

Let$Q$ be the linearly ordered set of all rational numbers con-sidered as a category, while $R^+$ is the set of reals with a symbol $\infty$  adjoined. In $Sets^Q$, prove that the subobject classifier $\Omega$ has $\Omega (q) = {r: r\in R^+, r\geq q}$.

I coud just write this:
$Hom_{Sets} (Hom_Q (q,-),\Omega) \cong sub_{Sets} (Hom_Q(q,-))=\Omega (q)$

For each $q\in Q ,  r\geq q$ define a subfunctor of $Hom_Q(q,-)$

$\infty$ defines a subfunctor for each $Hom(q,-)$

Then $\Omega (q) = \{r: r\in R^+, r\geq q\}$.

Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track here by applying the Yoneda lemma. You've correctly observed that at $q$ the subobject classifier is precisely determined by the subobjects of $y(q) = \hom(-, q)$. However, as written you're considering $\mathbf{Set}^\mathbb{Q}$, so we are not considering presheaves on $\mathbb{Q}$, but rather on $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathsf{op}}$. In other words, $\Omega(q)$ is the set of "upwards closed subsets of rational numbers larger than $q$".

Thinking of real number in terms of Dedekind cuts $(A, B)$, we can see that real numbers larger than $q$ precisely determine upwards closed *nonempty* subsets of rational numbers. In order to account for the empty subset, we throw in $\infty$ to obtain your desired characterization.

Comment: Sorry I don't get the dedekind cut part...

Comment: It might be worth looking up explicitly, but a Dedekind cut is one way of representing a real number (alternatives include things like Cauchy sequences). A Dedekind cut $(A, B)$ is a pair of non-empty disjoint sets of rationals $A$ and $B$ such that if $a \in A$ and $a' \le a$ then $a' \in A$ and (dually) $b \le b' \land b \in B \to b' \in B$ and $A$ doesn't contain greatest element. It turns out $A$ determines $B$ and vice versa, so a real number is precisely determined by an upwards closed set of rationals. The real number $B$ represents is small than some rational $q$ iff $q \in B$.

Comment: Accordingly, an upwards closed set of rational numbers larger than $q$ <=> a real number smaller than $q$.